# How do I count repeated occurrences of an element in a list?

Tags: java

Say I have an arraylist = `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6 2, 5, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5 ,2 ,6 ,3,5, 2, 5, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2,]`

I would like to find all the start indexes of a sequence of x.
The sequence length must be > 2
For example x = 1

My expected output is this: 
start at element 0, interval of size 5. 
start at element  13, interval of size 5. 
start at element 29, interval of size 6.

I am new to programming in java and I don't know what the logic would be.

I was thinking of using a for loop and looping through each element in the array and using a counter when the element i == 1. My problem is I'm not sure how to stop counting and resume counting between intervals.

```java
public void count() {
    int count = 0; 

    for(Integer number: ArrayList) {
        if (number == 1 ) {
            count++;
        }

        if (number != 1 ) {
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see my attempts are pretty bad. I'm missing something crucial and just can't see it.

Comment: Bader can you show expected output

Comment: First, edit the question and show us what you've tried so far. --- As for how to detect when a new "interval" starts, keep a variable for keeping track of the *previous* value.

Comment: *"how to stop counting"* You stop counting when a value is not 1. --- *"how to resume counting between intervals"* Why would you be counting when *between* "intervals"?

Comment: Hopefully I fixed the question!

Comment: I would suggest that you try this with paper and pencil. Write out the array above in large characters. Use two different coins, and you can *only* see the value of the array where one of the coins are. Since they are different, you can know two values. Now, write on paper what you're trying to do as the coins move (and each time they move, write that on the paper as well).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Noah! It seems like what you really need is to remember whether you're in the middle of a sequence of repeated list elements. I'd suggest a boolean called `isCounting`. If this element is 1 (or whatever number you're looking for), you set isCounting to true. if `isCounting`, you add one to your count because you're counting elements of a run. If not, set count to zero because you're not in a run. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5 ,2 ,6 ,3,5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2));
        int startIndex = -1;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a number to count: ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        numbers.add(x-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            if(numbers.get(i) == x){
                if(count == 0)
                startIndex = i;
                count++;
            } else{
                if(count > 2)
                System.out.printf("start at index %d,  interval of size %d \n", startIndex, count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a number to count: 1                                                                                                    
start at index 0,  interval of size 5                                                                                         
start at index 13,  interval of size 5                                                                                        
start at index 29,  interval of size 6
```

Comment: This answer asks for a number to count, and then throws it away, only ever comparing the list elements to 1. It should be `if (numbers[i] == x)` and that's just at a casual glance. There may be additional bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check sliding window approach:
https://medium.com/outco/how-to-solve-sliding-window-problems-28d67601a66

In general, you should use 2 pointers in the array,

The first one will indecte the beginning of the sequence, the second one will indecte about the length or the sequence.

You start moving with that start index untill you getting to you value, then moving with the second index untill reaching to a different number.

Then you record you result bye saving Pair of start index and length inside an ArrayList or any structure, and setting the startIndex =endindex+1

You can visit leetcode / geeksforgeeks for more related questions and topics

Answer (score -1):

> I am new to programming in java

...but this is not related to java, is it?

> I don't know what the logic would be.

That's what you need to solve before trying to implement it.

Hint: Can you implement something slightly different? Change the input to number occurrences of 1s in a list, so your output would be `[5, 5, 6, 1]`.

Hint 2: sometimes it's easier to add extra number (terminator) to original list, so let say if -1 cannot be there, add -1 to the end, so once you find -1, you know you are at the end...